# How to display pop-up only once per user on Shopify

Tags: shopify

I've applied Shopify's pop-up for the home page, but I only need it to load once per user so that if click off the page and come back you dont see the pop-up form again. Is there a code that I could insert in the "header.liquid" section of the theme?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to integrate with cookie. Let it display the dialog and store the value that the dialog has been shown in the cookie so it won't be displayed next time.

$(document).ready(function() {
var dialogShown = $.cookie('dialogShown');

```
// On newer versions of js-cookie, API use:
// var dialogShown = Cookies.get('dialogShown');

if (!dialogShown) {
    $(window).load(function(){
        $( "#dialog1" ).dialog();
        $.cookie('dialogShown', 1);
        // On newer versions of js-cookie, API use:
        // Cookies.set('dialogShown', 1);

    });
}
else {
    $("#dialog1").hide();
}
```

});